# Hardware MIDI Out for Playback in Java?

Tags: java, midi, midi-interface, javax.sound.midi

I am making a simple application to playback MIDI files in Java.
I am using the `javax.sound.midi` library.

I can retrieve my MIDI Out Device correctly (USB to MIDI Cable).

But when I playback the sequence it always plays in the default sound synthesizer which is the host OS's General Midi (Soundfont) playback.

The problem I am having is changing the default MIDI Out.

When I execute

```
Receiver MidiOutReceiver; //instantiated earlier
Sequencer MidiOutSequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
MidiOutSequencer.open();
MidiOutSequencer.start();
```

I hear the MIDI sequence reproduction out of the speakers.

After referring to the [documentation](http://jsresources.org/)

```
3.10.
The "Java Sound Sequencer" is implicitly connected to the default Synthesizer, 
3.5.
In your program you can obtain a Synthesizer instance yourself and connect 
it to a sequencer explicitly using a Transmitter / Receiver pair. 
So you know which Synthesizer is used. 
In case you obtained a Sequencer that is pre-connected to a Synthesizer,
you can find out the Synthesizer by using the method getTransmitters().
```

But there is not mention of how to explicitly use this Transmitter / Receiver pair and instantiate the Sequencer object with the new Default Synthesizer.

I have the correct Transmitter and Receiver. 
But they are not playing out of the MIDI out.

Also when I try

```
MidiSystem.getTransmitter().setReceiver(MidiOutReceiver);
```

It does not seem to change anything.

How do I explicitly use this Receiver / Transmitter Pair with a Synthesizer so that the Default Sequencer will use my MIDI out port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overlooked something simple. The default `Sequencer` returned by `MidiSystem.getSequencer();` has a Transmitter which in turn has a `setReceiver()` method to add a MIDI Out device. But you must have the correct MIDI Out device. I had chosen a wrong device by accident.

So first the correct output device is chosen by looking through the `DeviceInfos` array, picking the correct device, then instatiating the the `Sequencer` with the correct `Receiver`.

```
MidiDevice.Info[] MidiDeviceInfos = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();
//find the suitable device number here, based on some criteria
MidiDevice MidiOutDevice = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(MidiDeviceInfos[DEVICE_NUMBER]);
Receiver MidiOutReceiver = MidiOutDevice.getReceiver();
Sequencer MidiOutSequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
//Add the new MIDI out device here.
MidiOutSequencer.getTransmitter().setReceiver(MidiOutReceiver);
MidiOutSequencer.open();
```

Now you can `open()` a file and `play()` it, but since the default MIDI Out device is also used you may hear General MIDI/Soundfont MIDI sounds too. This threw me off at first but now the MIDI device will also be sending the opened sequence out of your added `Receiver`.

Comment: The documentation for `MidiDevice.getReceivers()` says "A receiver can be removed from the device by closing it." so presumably you can remove the default MIDI Out device with `for (Receiver receiver : MidiSystem.getSequencer().getReceivers()) receiver.close();`